# Calculate resolution of an image which is tilted

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, angle

I have an image that has a resolution of 768 x 662 (width x height). In this image there is another image which is tilted by 30 degrees.

Can I use these existing values (Resolution and Rotation) to calculate the resolution of the rotated image inside? If yes, how? Theoretically, the result in this example should output a longer width and a shorter height.

Comment: Computing the dimensions of the inner rectangle is not difficult, if that is what you want.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca thats what I want

Comment: Here's a hint for you: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kw8gn.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the inner picture have dimensions $ a \times b $ where side $a$ makes an angle of $30^\circ$ with the positive horizontal direction.

It follows that

$ 768 = a \cos 30^\circ + b \sin 30^\circ $

$ 662 = a \sin 30^\circ + b \cos 30^\circ $

which are two linear equations in the two unknowns $a$ and $b$.  It follows using Cramer's rule of solution that

$ a = \dfrac{ 768 \cos 30^\circ - 662 \sin 30^\circ }{ \cos^2 30^\circ - \sin^2 30^\circ } $

$ b = \dfrac{ 662 \cos 30^\circ - 768 \sin 30^\circ} { \cos^2 30^\circ - \sin^2 30^\circ } $

This evaluates to

$ a = 668 $

$b = 379 $